# Opening a link from postman response in an external browser

Tags: postman

I need to click a link in the postman response that loads an HTML page, then fill a form which makes an AJAX request followed by a redirect. Postman doesn't allow that, so I have to copy the link from the response and paste it in chrome which is a bit tedious and error-prone.

Is there a way to configure postman or use a key combination like (shift-click which doesn't work) to load the URL in an external browser?

Comment: I'm annoyed by exactly the same thing. Any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: This feature now exists from Postman version 6.1.2

Comment: Hit `Cmd` + `Click`

Answer (score 5):

From version 6.1.2 Cmd/Ctrl + Click will open the link in default browser.

> [See link](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2030)

Answer (score 2):

They opened an issue a few months before you asked this question ([link](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2030)) and it is till now unresolved.

There isn't any configuration or key combination available either.

Comment: Seems like this will be available in an upcoming release as of May 2018

Answer (score 0):

In the current online version you can right click in the response / preview pane and choose go to ... in the shortcut menu